# CFWheels not adding automatic validatesPresenceOf to NOT NULL field

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

I added a couple columns to a table in MySQL:

- `totalSavings DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`
- `totalDebt DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 0`

There are several other columns in the table configured in a similar manner, and CFWheels is appropriately adding a `validatesPresenceOf` validation to those properties.

But my new ones are not being picked up as required by CFWheels automatic validations. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, CFWheels will skip the `validatesPresenceOf` automatic validation if there is a `DEFAULT` value set on the column.

I needed to add the `DEFAULT 0` to the column initially so records would be set with that default. But then removing the default fixed the issue with the validation.